# Implementing data.table functions on mapply with rowwise iteration

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, mapply

I have a dataframe

```
df<-data.frame(var1=c(1:10),var2=c(rep(c(0,0.1),each=5)),BYGROUP_OBSNUM=c(0:4))
```

I want to calculate a column using the rowwise pseudo-formula

```
df$VAR1_NEW <-(ifelse (var2!=0 & BYGROUP_OBSNUM !=0),
 var1[i]+lag(var1,1)*var2^1+lag(var1,2)*var2^2 +....lag(var1,BYGROUP_OBSNUM)*var2^BYGROUP_OBSNUM)
```

Current approach-

```
my.func <- function(x){mapply(function(v1,v2,v3,n) {
  if(v2==0 | v3==0){
    as.numeric(v1)
  } else {
   sum(v1, x[rev(seq(1:(n-1))),1][1:v3] * v2 ^  seq(1:(n-1))[1:v3])
}
}, x[,"var1"], x[,"var2"], x[,"BYGROUP_OBSNUM"],seq(1:nrow(x)))
}

df1 <- df %>% 
  do(data.frame(., my.func(.))) %>%
  mutate(VAR1_NEW = my.func...)%>%
  select(-my.func...)
```

#Result-

> df1

```
var1 var2 BYGROUP_OBSNUM VAR1_NEW   

 1  0.0              0   1.0000
 2  0.0              1   2.0000
 3  0.0              2   3.0000
 4  0.0              3   4.0000
 5  0.0              4   5.0000
 6  0.1              0   6.0000
 7  0.1              1   7.6000
 8  0.1              2   8.7600
 9  0.1              3   9.8760
 10  0.1             4  10.9876
```

This approach is taking 6mins for a dataframe of 1.4 Million rows. Hence I want to change the approach to data.table which should take less time as a copy will not be created.

So far this is what I have achieved-

```
 DT<-as.data.table(df)
 DT<-DT[, c("New_Var1") := my.func(DT)]
```

But this throws a lot of warnings like-

```
>warnings()
10: In if (v2 == 0 | v3 == 0) { ... :
    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
11: In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(c("New.Var1"), my.func(DT))) :
    10 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector
12: In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(c("New.Var1"), my.func(DT))) :
    Supplied 100 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'New.Var1' (90 unused)
```

and just copies the var1 column into new_var1 as only 1st element is being used.

I am new to data.table usage and not able to find the workaround.

Comment: In the `ifelse` pseudocode, what is the `else` part.  Also where is the `lag` that is described in pseudocode in the `my.func`

Comment: else part is --> `new_var1=var1`. The formula is e.g. for the 8th row(8  0.1              2) in `df->new_var1=8+7*0.1+6*0.1^2` since var2 and BYGROUP_OBSNUM  are non-zero else `new_var1=var1`

Comment: Where is the `lag` in your `my,func`  Sorry, I am confused

Comment: `x[rev(seq(1:(n-1))),1][1:v3] ` gives the lag so for 8th row, the elements picked are `var1[7],var1[6] and then multiplied by  (0.1 0.01)`. This is finally `added to var1[8]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, grp := cumsum(BYGROUP_OBSNUM==0)
      ][, VAR1_NEW := Reduce(`+`, Map(`*`, shift(var1, 1:.N, fill = 0), 
       var2^(seq_len(.N)))) + var1, grp][, grp := NULL][]
#    var1 var2 BYGROUP_OBSNUM VAR1_NEW
# 1:    1  0.0              0   1.0000
# 2:    2  0.0              1   2.0000
# 3:    3  0.0              2   3.0000
# 4:    4  0.0              3   4.0000
# 5:    5  0.0              4   5.0000
# 6:    6  0.1              0   6.0000
# 7:    7  0.1              1   7.6000
# 8:    8  0.1              2   8.7600
# 9:    9  0.1              3   9.8760
#10:   10  0.1              4  10.9876
```

Comment: This is working fine for 20K rows but I have a 16GB RAM system and it breaks at 30K rows. The system hangs with full memory usage.

Comment: @Riya  For 20K rows, how much time did it take and compared with your `mapply` approach.  can u try on a fresh session?

Comment: 20K rows took 4secs. I tried on a fresh session each time.

Comment: @Riya Suppose if you try with the `mapply`, how much time it took for 20K

Comment: 20K rows took 4secs by data.table method and also 4secs by mapply approach. I tried on a fresh session each time.Will splitting the data help?

Comment: @Riya can you try the `base R` method i.e. `setDF(df); unsplit(lapply(split(df[1:2], cumsum(df[[3]]==0)), function(x) x$var1 + (head(embed(c(rep(0, nrow(x)), x$var1), nrow(x)), -1) %*% x$var2^(seq_len(nrow(x))))), cumsum(df[[3]]==0))#[1]  1.0000  2.0000  3.0000  4.0000  5.0000  6.0000  7.6000  8.7600  9.8760 10.9876`

Comment: this method takes 0.37 secs for 20K rows

Comment: The dataframe made here is 16MB (20K rows). This is taking 0.37secs, but my practical dataframe is 24MB (20K rows and 3 cols) and this is taking 35secs !

Comment: No, the base method is taking too much time for my data and data.table method is breaking the system at 30K rows.

Comment: @Riya This is a strange situation.  I understand the problem of memory as we are do the shift and it depends on the number of rows for each group.  May be it is better to use `for` loop and optimize with Rcpp

Comment: for loop was my 1st approach and that is a bad approach. Takes 12 mins for 1.4M rows! Mapply approach takes 6 mins. I am trying the split-apply-combine approach now.

Comment: I guess my data was not grouped properly. After grouping it, this function is taking 1.34 secs for 1.6 MM rows!! Thanks! Its finally perfect.

Comment: @Riya Thanks for the update and I am glad that you got it working

Comment: I found a solution to my challenges: `setDT(aaa)[,`:=`(VAR1_NEW = sapply(1:nrow(aaa), function(i) if (i!=1 | BYGROUP_OBSNUM[i] != 0) sum(var1[i],sum(var1[ (i-BYGROUP_OBSNUM[i]):(i-1) ]*var2[i]^(BYGROUP_OBSNUM[i]:1))) 
                                                              else var1[i]))][BYGROUP_OBSNUM == 0, `:=`(VAR1_NEW = var1 ) ]` . But htis takes a bit more time than the MapReduce function. Can the same formula be written in the MapReduce style ?

Comment: @RIya Could you show the new example for 'aaa'.  I guess you deleted that comment